# Converting ANSI operators in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, outer-join

Need help in converting the following 2 queries to ANSI compatible code. My code is using =* operators and I need to convert them into right outer join. I have given it a good attempt, however, not able to get the desired results.

## Query 1

```sql
SELECT m.MatterID, m.MatterType,
    m.HasSuppressionOrder, m.Complexity, 
    m.DateReceived, m.DateCompleted,
    ph.OfficerID, pe.Surname + ', ' + pe.GivenNames, h1.Result
FROM   CMS.MATTER m,
    CMS.PHASE ph,
    CMS.PERSON pe,
    CMS.HEARING h1
WHERE             
    (m.DateCompleted BETWEEN '2015-10-29 00:00:00' and '2015-10-30 00:00:00') 
    AND (ph.MatterID = m.MatterID 
    and ph.PhaseSeq = (SELECT MAX(ph2.PhaseSeq) FROM CMS.PHASE ph2 where ph2.MatterID = m.MatterID)) 
    AND (pe.PersonNo = (SELECT mp.PersonNo FROM CMS.MATTER_PERSON mp
            WHERE mp.MatterID = m.MatterID and mp.MatterPersonType = 'DEF')) 
    AND (h1.MatterID =* m.MatterID and --NON ANSI JOIN OPERATORS THAT NEED CONVERSION
    h1.PhaseSeq =* ph.PhaseSeq and --NON ANSI JOIN OPERATORS THAT NEED CONVERSION
    h1.HearingDateTime =* (SELECT MAX(h2.HearingDateTime)FROM CMS.HEARING h2 WHERE h2.MatterID = m.MatterID))
ORDER BY m.MatterID
```

## Query 2

```
SELECT  m.MatterID,
    m.MatterType,
    m.HasSuppressionOrder,
    m.DateReceived,
    ISNULL (ph.OfficerID, 'No Phase'),
    ISNULL (pe.Surname, 'No Accused Registered') + ', ' + pe.GivenNames,
    m.Complexity,
    m.ProgramCode,
    m.Comments,
    m.StaffGroup,
    m.StaffSubGroup
FROM   CMS.MATTER m,
    CMS.PHASE ph, 
    CMS.PERSON pe
WHERE m.DateReceived BETWEEN '2015-09-30 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-30 00:00:00'
    AND       ph.MatterID =* m.MatterID -- Taken care
    AND       ph.PhaseSeq =* (
        SELECT  MAX( PhaseSeq )
        FROM   CMS.PHASE
        WHERE MatterID = m.MatterID -- Taken care
    )
    AND pe.PersonNo =* (
        SELECT  PersonNo
        FROM   CMS.MATTER_PERSON
        WHERE MatterID = m.MatterID
           AND       MatterPersonType = 'DEF'
    )
```

I tried converting query 2 and wrote the following:

```
SELECT  m.MatterID,
    m.MatterType,
    m.HasSuppressionOrder,
    m.DateReceived,
    ISNULL (ph.OfficerID, 'No Phase'),
    ISNULL (pe.Surname, 'No Accused Registered') + ', ' + pe.GivenNames,
    m.Complexity,
    m.ProgramCode,
    m.Comments,
    m.StaffGroup,
    m.StaffSubGroup
FROM   CMS.PHASE ph
right join CMS.MATTER m ON ph.MatterID = m.MatterID
RIGHT JOIN CMS.PERSON pe ON ((SELECT  PersonNo FROM   CMS.MATTER_PERSON WHERE MatterID = m.MatterID AND MatterPersonType = 'DEF')= pe.PersonNo)
RIGHT JOIN CMS.PHASE ph2 ON ((SELECT  MAX(PhaseSeq) FROM CMS.PHASE ph WHERE ph.MatterID = m.MatterID)=ph2.PhaseSeq)
WHERE (m.DateReceived BETWEEN '2015-09-30 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-30 00:00:00')
```

===========================================

However, something is not right.

Comment: What are you expecting?  What is not right - "incorrect syntax" or "data not as expected"?

Comment: Those sub-selects in the ON conditions of your rewrite are ... dubious.  I'm not sure I even understand what those conditions are supposed to do.  Normally, a join condition identifies a column from one table and a column from another table and somehow tests their relation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this (QUERY2):

```
SELECT
    m.MatterID,
    m.MatterType,
    m.HasSuppressionOrder,
    m.DateReceived,
    ISNULL (ph.OfficerID, 'No Phase'),
    ISNULL (pe.Surname, 'No Accused Registered') + ', ' + pe.GivenNames,
    m.Complexity,
    m.ProgramCode,
    m.Comments,
    m.StaffGroup,
    m.StaffSubGroup
FROM CMS.MATTER m
INNER JOIN CMS.MATTER_PERSON mp
  ON mp.MatterID = m.MatterID AND mp.MatterPersonType = 'DEF'
LEFT JOIN CMS.PERSON pe ON pe.PersonNo = mp.PersonNo
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 ph.OfficerID
  FROM CMS.PHASE ph
  WHERE ph.MatterID = m.MatterID
  ORDER BY ph.PhaseSeq DESC
) ph
WHERE m.DateReceived BETWEEN '2015-09-30 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-30 00:00:00'
```

`CMS.MATTER` is mandatory part for sure and it's better to start from it and make `outer` joins to the rest of tables than to build tons of confusing `right` joins.

Double link to `ph` is not needed, but I'm not sure what was it supposed to be - `outer apply` or `cross apply`. `MAX( PhaseSeq )` was mandatory part, so may be it is more correct to use `cross apply`. But there is that `ISNULL(OfficerID, '')` in the original code which is telling us that it's possible not to have corresponding value... `MAX` is not needed since we are getting `TOP 1 DESC`.

`pe.PersonNo =* (SELECT  PersonNo` should return always a single row - otherwise it would fail - so, I guess, we can join it without any `TOP` or `MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a right join can generally be rewritten as a left join simply by swapping the tables. In my opinion, turning this into a left join, even with the old-style syntax, makes it easier to understand.

```
SELECT ...
FROM   CMS.MATTER m,
    CMS.PHASE ph, 
    CMS.PERSON pe
WHERE ...
AND m.MatterID *= ph.MatterID
AND (SELECT ...) *= ph.PhaseSeq
AND (SELECT ...) *= pe.PersonNo
```

This makes it more obvious that you can translate this into a select from `CMS.MATTER`, and left-join `CMS.PHASE` and `CMS.PERSON`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM CMS.MATTER m
LEFT JOIN CMS.PHASE ph
ON ph.MatterID = m.MatterID
AND ph.PhaseSeq = (SELECT ...)
LEFT JOIN CMS.PERSON pe
ON pe.PersonNo = (SELECT ...)
```